# Let T1 be the linear transformation corresponding to a counterclockwise rotation of 120 degrees

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T_1$ be the linear transformation corresponding to a counterclockwise rotation of $120$ degrees
and let $T_2$ be the linear transformation corresponding to a clockwise rotation of $45$ degrees.

Let $u = \begin{bmatrix} 4 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$. Evaluate $T_2(T_1(u))$?

**My work**

I used $\begin{pmatrix} cos\theta  & -sin\theta  \\ sin\theta  & cos\theta  \end{pmatrix}$

T1 = $\begin{pmatrix} cos(\frac { 2\Pi  }{ 3 } ) & -sin(\frac { 2\Pi  }{ 3 } ) \\ sin(\frac { 2\Pi  }{ 3 } ) & cos(\frac { 2\Pi  }{ 3 } ) \end{pmatrix}$

T1=$\begin{pmatrix} \frac { -1 }{ 2 }  & \frac { -\sqrt { 3 }  }{ 2 }  \\ \frac { \sqrt { 3 }  }{ 2 }  & \frac { -1 }{ 2 }  \end{pmatrix}$

T1(u)=$\begin{pmatrix} -2 &  \\ 2\sqrt { 3 }  &  \end{pmatrix}$

Similarly, T2 = $\begin{pmatrix} \frac { 1 }{ \sqrt { 2 }  }  & \frac { 1 }{ \sqrt { 2 }  }  \\ \frac { -1 }{ \sqrt { 2 }  }  & \frac { 1 }{ \sqrt { 2 }  }  \end{pmatrix}$, Here I took $\theta$=$\frac { 7\pi }{ 4 }$

Now, T2(T1(u)) = $\begin{pmatrix} \frac { 1 }{ \sqrt { 2 }  }  & \frac { 1 }{ \sqrt { 2 }  }  \\ \frac { -1 }{ \sqrt { 2 }  }  & \frac { 1 }{ \sqrt { 2 }  }  \end{pmatrix}$ $\begin{pmatrix} -2 &  \\ 2\sqrt { 3 }  &  \end{pmatrix}$

Finally, I got T2(T1(u)) = $\begin{pmatrix} \frac { -2 }{ \sqrt { 2 }  } +\frac { 2\sqrt { 3 }  }{ 2 }  & \frac {  }{  }  \\ \frac { 2 }{ \sqrt { 2 }  } +\frac { 2\sqrt { 3 }  }{ 2 }  &  \end{pmatrix}$

Can anyone please verify my work. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made a mistake as you compute $T_1(u)$:$$T_1(u)=\begin{pmatrix} -2  \\ 2\sqrt { \color{red}3 }    \end{pmatrix}$$

$$\begin{pmatrix} \frac { 1 }{ \sqrt { 2 }  }  & \frac { 1 }{ \sqrt { 2 }  }  \\ \frac { -1 }{ \sqrt { 2 }  }  & \frac { 1 }{ \sqrt { 2 }  }  \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} -2   \\ 2\sqrt { 3 }    \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} -\sqrt2+\sqrt6   \\ \sqrt2+\sqrt6   \end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: I figured that one, thanks... so the final answer will be $\begin{pmatrix} \frac { -2 }{ \sqrt { 2 }  } -\frac { 2\sqrt { 3 }  }{ 2 }  & \frac {  }{  }  \\ \frac { 2 }{ \sqrt { 2 }  } +\frac { 2\sqrt { 3 }  }{ 2 }  &  \end{pmatrix}$ right

Comment: can't be right, the net rotation is $75^\circ$ which is an acute angle, both component should be positive.

Comment: for the T2, I took $\theta$=$7\pi/4$.. Because, it mentioned that it is clock-wise. so, I went backwards from 360

Comment: that is alright, the angle is correct.

Comment: i think you still made a mistake in your calculation. I have included my answer, try and see if you can get that.

Comment: Thanks, I got it now.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{pmatrix} \frac { 1 }{ \sqrt { 2 }  }  & \frac { 1 }{ \sqrt { 2 }  }  \\ \frac { -1 }{ \sqrt { 2 }  }  & \frac { 1 }{ \sqrt { 2 }  }  \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} -2 &  \\ 2\sqrt { 3 }  &  \end{pmatrix}=$$

$$\begin{pmatrix} \frac { -2 }{ \sqrt { 2 }  } -\frac { 2\sqrt { 3 }  }{ 2 }  & \frac {  }{  }  \\ \frac { 2 }{ \sqrt { 2 }  } +\frac { 2\sqrt { 3 }  }{ 2 }  &  \end{pmatrix}$$is not  quite right. check the signs

Comment: I edited now, can you please tell me whether this is right or not

Comment: I have doubt on the angle I took in the T2

Comment: Now it is correct. Your angle in T2 is ok. You could have picked $-\pi /4,$ with the same result.